# Singleton or Signal and Slots?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am trying to reimplement or modify a tab code in a gui application. They are currently using Qt signal and slots system to handle addition and removal of tabs from the tab bar (For example if a tab was being drag from one tab widget to another, the old tab widget will signal the new tab widget that a new tab is coming). I was thinking rather than using that, I could simplify things using a thread safe singleton class. Then when ever a tab is moved, the widget just call on the singleton rather than emitting a signal.

Thanks

Comment: So, you want to break the way Qt is supposed to work?

Comment: How will that simplify the code? You'd need to correctly implement a thread-safe singleton, then rewrite all that code. Emitting a signal is a single statement with Qt.

Answer (score 5):

**Signals and Slots.**

Without even starting why the singleton would be bad, the way the data is updated inside Qt would be messed up by the singleton approach.

Comment: Well that wont be the case, since the data is still managed by the internal Qt functions. The internal Qt Functions of the Tab will be called by the manager singleton which will provide an interface for the tabs to interact with their containers (most likely MDI Sub Windows) without the tab having pointer to their containers. So Imagine if I have an infinite amount of tabs in the program, the manager will be responsible for the tabs and which container they go in. If a drag and drop even occurs the singleton will just notify the proper widget that an event has occurured and you need to react.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do that. You are working within an environment and should use the mechanism the framework provides. What about if the UI in the future will have multiple windows and maybe multiple instances?

If possible you should always try to use the way from the framework you are using. This will also help in the future for the maintenance (upgrades, new hires, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a singleton, which will accept messages and dispatch them back ? *(note: if you use a garden variety object instead of a singleton, you're essentially implementing an Observer pattern).*

Then you are reinventing signals and slots, which use a global state internally. Instead of putting work in reinventing some difficult piece of code, why don't you use the already existing **signals and slots** ?